# What does happen to electrons in the weak force decay?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, electrons, weak-interaction

What happen with the Electrons produced in Stars due to the weak force decay? Do they combine with other atoms? Are they just pushed out of the Sun? Do they help with the electron degenerative pressure? OR they are used again to produce another neutron? Or Physicist are not sure yet?

Comment: If the question is about fusion products in the sun then you are mostly talking about positrons (anti-electrons), and that makes a big difference.

Comment: @dmckee, no, I am most interested to understand what happen with the electron produced during the decay of neutron or weak force interaction.

Comment: They are part of the plasma , see my answer here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/302370/plasma-and-stars

Comment: @ ann v see this comment: do you believe that partially answers my question, or solar winds have nothing to do with weak force decay?
https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/13582/is-solar-wind-positively-charged

Answer (score -1):

**Short Answer**: Electrons are not bound in the plasma of the star, so they roam around freely after any decay process with two exceptions.

1. If they are at the core.
2. When a star is undergoing collapse.

At the core, fusion is taking place so any free electrons/protons will fuse together to create heavier elements thereby keeping the pressure of the fusion matched with the gravitational pull.

If the fusion pressure is not enough, the star undergoes a collapse. When a star is undergoing collapse, and if the gravitational attraction is great enough to pass the electron degeneracy pressure, the compressed electrons with protons will form neutrons. If the neutron degeneracy pressure is greater than the gravitational attraction, this is how you obtain a neutron star. If the gravitational attraction is greater still, the neutron degeneracy pressure fails and you obtain a black hole.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but maybe my question is not clear. I am most interested to understand where  electrons produced during a beta decay or W and Z bosons decays end up. Meaning, sure, a neutron can decay and produce a proton, electron and anti-electronneutrino, but what happen with electron, what is its new function? Does it keep floating around? Is it required to combine with the proton?

Comment: Ahh I see. Sorry, should have elaborated a bit more. The electrons are in a plasma so the beta decay, or W/Z decay products are not bound inside the star. So most of the time, the electron floats around, yes. However, this changes when you enter the core where fusion is actually taking place. So at the core, the electron is not free.

Comment: Just another addendum, this [**wiki**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton%E2%80%93proton_chain_reaction) might help.

Comment: thanks, so electrons can exist without being attached to an nucleus. In this case, per heavier densities of other objects, is it fair to concluded that electrons would be pushed out of the crust of the Sun into the corona?

Comment: Her Ernesto, I've edited the answer to be clearer. 

To answer your most recent question, the electron is free within the star. Theoretically it would make its way to the corona, just like photons, but its more likely to remain within the star. This is because, while the electron is not bound, there is still a significant electromagnetic force produced by the star on the electron. The E&M force won't cause photons to escape from the star, but it will effectively trap the electrons inside the star. The exception being that for high velocity, electrons could bounce around until they escape.

Comment: thanks, so it is possible that the electrons would form the corona then? And if the electrons escape, have we ever detected an income electron from the Sun?

Comment: Hi Ernesto, if I have answered the question, please let me know. With regards to your most recent questions, the corona is still actively being studied but there are undoubtedly electrons, protons, and hydrogen particles near the corona. The detection of incoming electrons is verified from solar winds.